# How to find gaps in a tile and geometry of tables in a faster way

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table that contains polygons within a tile and it is huge. I want to find the gaps in a tile, i.e. where polygons are not present within a tile. I came up with this query but it takes a lot of time.

```
SELECT (st_dump(ST_DIFFERENCE(m.geom::geography::geometry, 
ST_Union( ST_MakeValid(e.geom::geography::geometry))))).geom
    FROM tile m
    JOIN geom_table e on e.tile_id = m.feat_id
    WHERE  st_isvalidreason(e.geom) = 'Valid Geometry'
    GROUP BY e.tile_id, m.geom;
```

mainly because I think it is doing union of all geometries in a table. Could there be a better approach to it using PostGIS functions?

Comment: There are a few things you could clean up first before worrying about performance -- do the ST_MakeValid before any unioning and there is no need to cast to geography and then geometry (this may not take much time, but it is pointless, and make it harder to read). Could you also define what you mean by huge and a lot of time, how big the polygons are relative to the tile, how much overlap, etc.

Comment: Using `m.geom` in the `GROUP BY` seems suspect, especially since grouping by `e.tile_id` should be the same thing.  You might look at doing the union in a subquery, and then joining to the tile table using `LATERAL` to do the difference.